# How to loop a user back to the start of the program with two loops

Tags: java

I have created a overtime calculator which issues a warning to the user if they input more than 49 hours and loops back to the where the user inputs hours to use valid ones.

How do I issue a loop within a loop if someone enters the correct hours and want to issue another query? As it is currently set in a loop already.

specificity :

```
System.out.println ("Would you like to view another account? Y/N: ");
inputLine.next().charAt(0);
```

Here's full code to diagnose:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Overtime
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner inputLine = new Scanner( System.in );

        String staffName;
        int i = 1;

        double hoursWorked = 0, hourlyRate = 15, totalPay = 0, nationalInsurance = 0, tax = 0, netPay = 0, overtime = 0;

        System.out.print( "Enter employee name: " );

        staffName = inputLine.nextLine();
        do
        {
            System.out.print( "Enter number of hours worked: " );

            hoursWorked = inputLine.nextFloat();
            if( hoursWorked <= 36 )
            {
                totalPay = (hourlyRate * hoursWorked);
            }
            else if( hoursWorked >= 37 && hoursWorked <= 40 )
            {
                totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5);
            }
            else //(hoursWorked > 41 ) 
            {
                totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (41 - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2);
            }

            if( hoursWorked >= 37 && hoursWorked <= 40 )
            {
                overtime = (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5);
            }
            else if( hoursWorked > 41 )
            {
                overtime = (41 - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2);
            }

            if( totalPay > 155 )
            {
                nationalInsurance = (totalPay * 0.12);
            }


            tax = (totalPay * 0.20);
            netPay = (totalPay - tax - nationalInsurance);

            if( hoursWorked >= 49 )
            {
                System.out.println( "You are not legally allowed to work over 48 hours! " );
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println( "***********************" );
                System.out.println( "Employee: " + staffName );
                System.out.println( "Total Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked );
                System.out.println( "Overtime Pay: " + overtime );
                System.out.println( "Net Pay: " + totalPay );
                System.out.println( "Tax: " + tax );
                System.out.println(
                        "National insurance: " + (nationalInsurance = Math.round( nationalInsurance * 100.00 ) / 100.00) );
                System.out.println( "Net Pay" + netPay );
                i++;
                System.out.println( "Would you like to view another account? Y/N: " );
                inputLine.next().charAt( 0 );

                //System.out.println ("Overtime Pay" + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2));
                //System.out.println ("Total Deductions " + (totalPay * (20/100) + (totalPay * (4/100))));
            }
        }
        while( i == 1 );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change list line of your do block to:

```
if(inputLine.nextLine().charAt(0)!='Y') i=0;
```

So, if users enters no (or something else) then value of i will get changed to 0 and the loop will break.

A alternative and good way is to use i as a char variable and initially set its value to be 'Y' and then use

```
i=inputLine.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

and

```
while(i=='Y'||i=='y');
```

Also, code shouldn't do excessive and unnecessary things, that would be a bad design!
If hours are more than 48 then there is no need to calculate anything and it should loop back where user will enter hours again. So, just after taking input check that if it exceeds 48 hours or not. If it is less than 49 then in one block do all the calculation and print and ask if user wants to enter another input. And if hours>48 then print the message that it is invalid and again ask user for input.

Here's the code to it

```
import java.util.*;

public class Overtime
{
public static void main ()
{
    Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);

    String staffName;
    char i = 'Y';

    double hoursWorked = 0, hourlyRate = 15, totalPay=0, nationalInsurance=0, tax=0, netPay=0, overtime=0;

    System.out.print ("Enter employee name: ");

    staffName = inputLine.nextLine();
    do{
    System.out.print ("Enter number of hours worked: ");

    hoursWorked = inputLine.nextFloat();

    if (hoursWorked >= 49 )
    {
     System.out.println ("You are not legally allowed to work over 48 hours! ");
    } 

    else 
    {


    if ( hoursWorked <= 36 ) 
    {
        totalPay = (hourlyRate * hoursWorked);
    } 
    else if ( hoursWorked >= 37 && hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5);
    } 
    else  //(hoursWorked > 41 ) 
    {
        totalPay = (hourlyRate * 36) + (41-36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2);
    }

    if ( hoursWorked >= 37 && hoursWorked <= 40)
    {
        overtime = (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5);
    }
    else if ( hoursWorked > 41)
    {
        overtime = (41-36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate *2);
    }

    if (totalPay > 155 )
    {
        nationalInsurance = (totalPay * 0.12);
    }


    tax = (totalPay * 0.20);
    netPay = (totalPay - tax - nationalInsurance);

    System.out.println ( "***********************");
    System.out.println ("Employee: " + staffName);
    System.out.println ("Total Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked);
    System.out.println ("Overtime Pay: " + overtime);
    System.out.println ("Net Pay: " + totalPay); 
    System.out.println ("Tax: " + tax);
    System.out.println ("National insurance: " + (nationalInsurance = Math.round(nationalInsurance * 100.00 )/ 100.00));
    System.out.println ("Net Pay" + netPay);
    i++;
    System.out.println ("Would you like to view another account? Y/N: ");
    i=inputLine.nextLine().charAt(0);

    //System.out.println ("Overtime Pay" + (hoursWorked - 36) * (hourlyRate * 1.5) + (hoursWorked - 41) * (hourlyRate * 2));
    //System.out.println ("Total Deductions " + (totalPay * (20/100) + (totalPay * (4/100))));
    }
  }
  while(i == 'Y'||i=='y');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be looking at the result of the call to inputLine.next().charAt(0);

You're allowed to put the whole of what you have in here inside another loop, which you could make conditional on the output of that call.

However, I strongly advise you to restructure this code so that it makes logical sense to you when you read it, rather than have it all in one big method call.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you taking a look at the following code and comparing it against your own. From here you can see the differences and the loop makes more sense. If a user no longer wants to enter more accounts then pressing `N` will exit the loop.

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Scanner inputLine = new Scanner( System.in );
    String staffName, quit;
    double hoursWorked = 0, hourlyRate = 15, totalPay = 0, nationalInsurance = 0, tax = 0, netPay = 0, overtime = 0;

    do
    {
        System.out.print( "Enter employee name: " );
        staffName = inputLine.next();

        System.out.print( "Enter number of hours worked: " );
        hoursWorked = inputLine.nextFloat();

        /**
         * All other logic.
         */

        if( hoursWorked >= 49 )
        {
            System.out.println( "You are not legally allowed to work over 48 hours! " );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "The output" );
        }

        System.out.println ("Would you like to create another account? Y/N: ");
        quit = inputLine.next();
    }
    while( !quit.equalsIgnoreCase( "N" ) );
}
```